# How to identify the running graphic card in a system with more than one?

Tags: wmi, gpu

I need to identify the running graphic card in systems with more than one (typically computers with an integrated gc and a GPU as nVidia or ATI) in Windows systems.

I'm doing most of the other identifications using WMI but I have not found a way of detect which graphic card is being used.

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Just as a note, I have a computer with two adapters and they are both currently in use, each driving a separate display.

Comment: Ah, yes is another possibility. I'm focusing first in only one display.